# download data using web client through proxies on a C# console application

Tags: c#, proxy, console-application, webclient, webproxy

I have written a code to hit a particular URL and download data using a WebClient, and have set a proxy which I have purchased from MyPrivateProxies.net to this webclient with credentials and other needed parameters through which it hits the mentioned URL.

But I get this exception every time at the last line.

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond

below is my snippet of code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("my_proxy_with_port");
NetworkCredential netcredit = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
client.Credentials = netcredit;
webProxy.Credentials = netcredit;
webProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
webProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
client.Proxy = webProxy;
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

String strURL = "url_to_be_hit";
String jsonString = client.DownloadString(strURL);
```

Do I need some other settings on my windows 7 system or any config changes in `app.config`?

Are there other configuration for a console app to use proxies?

Comment: Either your proxy or the request URI points to an unavailable host. Try doing some research on this very common error and double-check the strings you're passing.

Comment: I have the feeling that both `my_proxy_with_port` and `url_to_be_hit` aren't valid arguments ...

Comment: my_proxy_with_port = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:29842 and url_to_be_hit= https://www.bing.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to assign the proxy credentials to the WebProxy object, not to the WebClient.

I dont know myprivateproxies.net but you have to make sure that you are using a http proxy, not a socks proxy or something else.

Answer (score 0):

got it resolved wasn't my code issue or URI points or any of my strings which I was passing...the port was not opened at my end on local system